# Updating nlme models after using reformulate()

Tags: r, nlme

Having a small issue with updating `nlme` models after using reformulate in the formula argument of `lme()`

Here is some data

```
set.seed(345)
A0 <- rnorm(4,2,.5)
B0 <- rnorm(4,2+3,.5)
A1 <- rnorm(4,6,.5)
B1 <- rnorm(4,6+2,.5)
A2 <- rnorm(4,10,.5)
B2 <- rnorm(4,10+1,.5)
A3 <- rnorm(4,14,.5)
B3 <- rnorm(4,14+0,.5)
score <- c(A0,B0,A1,B1,A2,B2,A3,B3)
id <- rep(1:8,times = 4, length = 32)
time <- factor(rep(0:3, each = 8, length = 32))
group <- factor(rep(c("A","B"), times =2, each = 4, length = 32))
df <- data.frame(id = id, group = group, time = time,  score = score)
```

Now say I want to specify the variables as objects outside the `lme` function...

```
t <- "time"
g <- "group"
dv <- "score"
```

...and then reformulate them...

```
mod1 <- lme(fixed = reformulate(t, response = "score"),
            random = ~1|id, 
            data = df)

summary(mod1)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: df 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  101.1173 109.1105 -44.55864

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | id
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:   0.5574872 0.9138857

Fixed effects: reformulate(t, response = "score") 
                Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  3.410345 0.3784804 21  9.010626       0
time1        3.771009 0.4569429 21  8.252693       0
time2        6.990972 0.4569429 21 15.299445       0
time3       10.469034 0.4569429 21 22.911036       0
 Correlation: 
      (Intr) time1  time2 
time1 -0.604              
time2 -0.604  0.500       
time3 -0.604  0.500  0.500

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.6284111 -0.5463271  0.1020036  0.5387158  2.1784156 

Number of Observations: 32
Number of Groups: 8
```

So far so good. But what if we want to add terms to the fixed effects portion of the model using `update()`?

```
mod2 <- update(mod1, reformulate(paste(g,"*",t), response = "score"))
```

We get the error message

```
Error in reformulate(t, response = "score") : 
  'termlabels' must be a character vector of length at least one
```

Obviously I can write the model out again without using `update()` but I was just wondering if there is a way to make update work.

I gather the problem lies in the way that `lme` encodes the formula argument when using `reformulate`.

Any solution much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you don't put in  formula literal in the call to `lme`, certain types of functions don't work. In particular, the place where the error is coming from is

```
formula(mod1)
#  Error in reformulate(t, response = "score") : 
#  'termlabels' must be a character vector of length at least one
```

The `nlme:::formula.lme` tries to evaluate the parameter in the wrong environment. A different way to construct the first model would be

```
mod1 <- do.call("lme", list(
  fixed = reformulate(t, response = "score"),
  random = ~1|id, 
  data = quote(df)))
```

When you do this, this injects the formula into the call

```
formula(mod1)
# score ~ time
```

which will allow the `update` function to change the formula.

Comment: Great solve @MrFlick. And thank you for the explanation. `do.call` is one of those functions which I have seen advanced R people use but have never quite understood. Why does `do.call` result in the rendering of the formula in a way that can be understood downstream but the original does not? What does it do?